# Why $\mathbb{P}(Z_n > 0) \leq \mu^n$?

Tags: probability, limits, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $Z_n$ be the number of children at generation $n$ of branching process with mean progeny $\mu$. Let $X_{n,i}$ be the number of children of the $i$-th node at generation $n-1$. Then, I know that
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{Z_{n-1}}X_{n,i} \middle | Z_{n-1}\right] = \mu Z_{n-1}.$$
Apparently one can use this and Markov's inequality to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(Z_n > 0) = 0$ for $\mu < 1$.

I suspect I would need $\mu < 1$ because I would probably get an upper bound for $\mathbb{P}(Z_n > 0)$ which is $\mu^n$. However, how can I show that that's indeed the case?

Sure,
$$\mathbb{E}[Z_n] = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{Z_{n-1}}X_{n,i} \middle | Z_{n-1}\right] \right] = \mathbb{E}[\mu Z_{n-1}] = \mu\mu^{n-1} = \mu^n$$

But I don't see how to link this result with the bound for $\mathbb{P}(Z_n > 0)$.

Comment: Hint: $Z_n$ is non-negative, integer-valued thus we have $$\mathbb{E}\left[ Z_n \right] = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}\left(Z_n > i \right).$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$P(Z_n>0)=P(Z_n \geq 1)$ (because $Z_n$ is integer valued). Hence, $P(Z_n>0)=P(Z_n \geq 1)\leq EZ_n=\mu^{n}$.

Comment: But why $P(Z_n \geq 1) \leq E[Z_n]$?

Comment: @Vicky Markov's inequality: $P(X \geq c ) \leq \frac {EX} c$ for any $c>0$ and any positive r.v. $X$.